# Is there a way to send variable values to a python script or a way to print the value into a text file?

Tags: pine-script

i am trying to use take values from indicator scripts that are written in pine-script and use them to make desicions in a python, is there a way to send the values to the python script or write them into a text file so the python script can read them from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an inherently complex way, yes, it is doable.

Pine scripts (and the Tradingview interface in general) can create Alerts where you can create an `Alert message` with any custom data (meaning, you can send whatever you want).

Those alerts can trigger a HTTP request with the above alert message attached so it can talk to a webserver, sending your data payload along with it. Now you just need to set up your own webserver and have your python app run under that webserver and you have just connected a Pine script with your Python code.

Why not code the logic in Pine script, or why not get that indicator value from other - easily accessible - source?

Comment: i don't think that i can use pine with binance api, i could make the indicators in python but then i would lose some of the functions that the ta lib gives me.

Comment: but can indicators communicate in tradingview, like could i make it so that if all indicator values are above/ below some level the script buys/sells automatically? that is pretty much what i am trying to do but i haven't dealt with this kind of stuff before

Comment: I don't want to advertise here, but this was exactly my issue, so I used 3Commas.io (free tier). They have DCA bots that can be connected to exchanges, Binance is among them. They have created the `Bots API` so that it can be called in a single HTTP request (along with all data, login token, bot command, everything). And this is the way how Tradingview can emit HTTP requests so this is a perfect match. I format my alert messages the way Tradingview expects it, I put that message into an Alert and on certain condition I trigger the alert. That will call the bot with the alert message.

Comment: @Kristen: You cannot connect two indicators/strategies in any way. If you need the same 'functionality' as of an indicator, you have to reprogram it in your Strategy. Fortunately, many indicators are open source and you can copy/paste their code.
So if you want a basic RSI indicator and you want to buy when its value exceeds a certain limit, you need to create a new Strategy, copypaste the freely available RSI code into your Strategy, understand that copypasted code (RSI is not that complex) and put its return value into a variable which you can compare to some value.

Comment: A few months later, Tradingview has some new features, where an Indicator can use another Indicator's output (attached to the same chart) as a data source. I have not experimented with this but I see this as some form of connection.